# In Node JS, how do i create an endpoint pass through? I'm using express and http

Tags: javascript, node.js, endpoints

In Node JS, how do i create an endpoint pass through? 
I'm using express and http
The entire app will be a just a series of pass through endpoints.
Here is my code

```
// the real endpoint is somewhere else. 
// for example http://m-engine.herokuapp.com/api/getstudents2
var http = require('http');
var options = {
   host: 'http://m-engine.herokuapp.com',
   path: '/api/getstudents2',
   method: 'GET'
};



app.get('/api/getstudents', function(req, res){

    // now past the request through
    http.request(options, function(response2) {
        response2.on('data', function (data) {
            res.json(data);
        });
    }).end();

});
```

Comment: so whenever any api request comes to domain x with api endpoint /api/* , then you want to redirect it to http://m-engine.herokuapp.com with endpoint /api/*     is this you want to achieve?

Comment: couldn't you just do `response2.pipe(res)` since you just want it to pass through the `readable` and `writable` stream?

Comment: @HirenS. no no redirect, pass through

Comment: @shriek I'll give that a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `bouncy` or `node-http-proxy` module for node.js to achieve the same thing.

Here is the sample code for `bouncy`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var bouncy = require('bouncy');

bouncy(function (req, bounce) {

        bounce("http://m-engine.herokuapp.com");

}).listen(8000);
```

Although, you can achieve the same thing with help of nginx also. No need to create node service for the same thing. Search on google for `nginx proxy_pass`. You can get examples for the same.

Comment: thanks for your reply. must be node, sorry. your code didn't make sense. do you mean the bouncy nests inside the app.get ?

Comment: have been using other libraries such as express-http-proxy as well